# change color of inputtextfield on select booleancheckbox

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a form in which there is a selectbox, and a inputtext field with default red color.

I want to change color of inputtextfield when that checkbox is selected.

How can I do that?

I am trying to achieve in this way, but unable to get change color.

pojo:

```
private Boolean changeColor=false;
    private boolean sign1;

public void ChangeColorEvent(){
        System.out.println("inside color change event");

        changeColor=true;
        sign1=true;
        }



<h:outputText value="understood and Signed?: " />  
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  label="Yes" value="#{patient.sign1}" >
            <p:ajax update="hppa1" listener="#{patient.ChangeColorEvent}" /> 
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <h:panelGroup>
    <p:inputText id="hppa" size="5" style="color:White;background:Red;" rendered="#{!patient.changeColor}" />
    <p:inputText id="hppa1" size="5" rendered="#{patient.changeColor}" style="color:White;background:Green;"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Please read about the `change()` and `css()` method of `jQuery`. The answer lies there. And please do mention what have you tried so far in the question. Just asking a question without even trying won't fetch you any answers here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have edited my question, please tell me what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the approach suggested by Daniel. Or a slightly different version would be this

```
<p:inputText id="hppa1" size="5" style="#{patient.changeColor eq true ? 'color:White;background:Green;' : 'color:White;background:Red;'}"/>
```

Saves you unnecessary markup and processing!

UPDATE: btw, you can very well handle these events in Javascript if you do not need any server side reflection of the `sign1` boolean flag

Comment: its working fine.but when but when i go to back or next page and agin  comes to same page, it remains clicked , it should get comes his initial stage until i save it.
if I refreshed also,it should need to its intial satge(i.e by default red and unclicked) right?

Comment: Unless you use `RequestScoped` or `ViewScoped` bean, you are going to face this problem. That is why my first comment was a `jQuery` (client side) solution. I think @Fallup has given exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach with **jQuery** using `styleClass` as @Daniel mentioned would be like this :
Define style classes in your `css`:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Have just one `p:inputText` (your approach with switching between two of them is really wrong) and add a `styleClass="red"` to it.

```
<p:inputText id="inputID" styleClass="red"/>
```

Then define this function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeColor(param){
          if (jQuery("[id*="+param+"]").hasClass('red')){
              jQuery("[id*="+param+"]").removeClass('red');
              jQuery("[id*="+param+"]").addClass('blue');
          }
          else {
              jQuery("[id*="+param+"]").removeClass('blue');
              jQuery("[id*="+param+"]").addClass('red');

          }

        };
    </script>
```

And use it in `p:selectBooleanCheckbox`:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox onchange="changeColor('inputID')"/>
```

**Note 1:** `[id*="+param+"]` in jQuery is because primefaces adds `ids` to your element (`p:inputText`) depending on what wraps it (eg. `form`, `dataTable`, ...). With `[id*="+param+"]` you can basically escape these added `ids` and find your desired `inputText`.

**Note 2:** If you want to work only with red class you can use :

```
function changeColor(param){
              jQuery("[id*="+param+"]".toggleClass('red'));       
            };
```

EDIT: This approach has no problem with initial stage which you mentioned in comment to @NikhilPatil answer.

Answer (score 1):

for start add id to your `<h:panelGroup id="myWrapper">`

and change the `p:ajax` to this `<p:ajax update="myWrapper" ....`

You can't update elements that are not rendered... read this [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370268/617373)

Or , an alternative solution (since you are using primefaces) is to change your `<h:panelGroup>` into `<p:outputPanel id="panel" autoUpdate="true">` and leave alll the rest the way it was

> Output panel is a container element with several use cases, this example uses an autoUpdate outputPanel to update a component page which doesn't exist on page initially and rendered based on a condition.

[Output Panel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/outputPanel.jsf)

But the way you are trying to change color is completely wrong... instead of hiding and displaying the element you should modify the css attributes of ONE element...

define 2 css classes like this

```
.classOne{
    color:White;
    background:Red;
}


.classTwo{
    color:White;
    background:Green;
}

.classThree{
    color:White;
    background:Blue;
}
```

and change the `styleClass=""` of your `<p:inputText id="hppa1"`

like this

```
 <p:inputText id="hppa1" styleClass="#{patient.className}".....
```

add `String changeColor` to your bean + getter/setter and change its values from `classOne` to `classTwo` ....