# commandLink with ajax doesnt work in JSF2

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I have problem with f:ajax tag. I want to show and hide some data after click on commandLink but i get error:

[image: error from browser]

My code:

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="contactDataForm">
    <h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{cc.attrs.userBB.showHideEditForm()}">
        <f:ajax render="editableContactData notEditableContactData"/>
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:panelGroup id="notEditableContactData" rendered="#{cc.attrs.userBB.show == false}">
        test1
    </h:panelGroup>
        test2
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the errors that you are getting is cause you are trying to refer to elements that are not rendered from your `f:ajax` , instead : refer to the wrappers of `h:panelGroup` that may or may not be rendered

Wrap the `notEditableContactData` , so basically :

try to change

```
<h:panelGroup id="notEditableContactData" rendered="#{cc.attrs.userBB.show == false}">
    test1
</h:panelGroup>
```

into

```
<h:panelGroup id="notEditableContactData" rendered="#{cc.attrs.userBB.show == false}">
   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{cc.attrs.userBB.show == false}">
        test1
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

do the same for the other `h:panelGroup` too

take a look at this answer of mine [Can you update an h:outputLabel from a p:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370268/617373)