# Rendering a component using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf

I have the following `HTML/JSF` elements in a `JSF` form:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <h:commandButton type="button" styleClass="btn btn-inverse" value="One Way"><f:ajax render="flexibleDates" listener="#{searchFlightsBean.setDirectionOneWay}"/></h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton type="button" styleClass="btn btn-inverse" value="Round Trip"><f:ajax render="flexibleDates" listener="#{searchFlightsBean.setDirectionRoundtrip}"/></h:commandButton>
</div>

<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="flexibleDates" rendered="#{searchFlightsBean.directionInd.label == 'Return'}">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{searchFlightsBean.flexibleDates}" styleClass="flight-results-left-padding checkbox inline"/>
    <h:outputText value="+/- 3 days"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

I have code in the backend bean like so:

```
public void setDirectionOneWay(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
    this.directionInd = DirectionInd.ONEWAY;
    log.info("setting direction to oneway " + directionInd.label);
}

public void setDirectionRoundtrip(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
    this.directionInd = DirectionInd.RETURN;
    log.info("setting direction to return " + directionInd.label);
}
```

The logs reflect that the code is working just fine.

However, the `panelGrid` that is supposed to get rendered stays visible, showing no sign. Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, that's the solution I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add wrapper to that `h:panelGrid` and point to it in your `f:ajax` instead of the original `h:panelGrid`

For example:

```
<f:ajax render="flexibleDatesWrapper"...


<h:panelGroup id="flexibleDatesWrapper">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="flexibleDates" rendered="#{searchFlightsBean.directionInd.label == 'Return'}">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{searchFlightsBean.flexibleDates}" styleClass="flight-results-left-padding checkbox inline"/>
        <h:outputText value="+/- 3 days"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Read this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370268/617373)

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. I read the other question, but didn't fully understand it. Should I still user `render` in the ajax element like you said in your code, or should I use `update`? (Just want to be clear)

Comment: You are welcome, you should use `render`. In the other question the user was using primefaces library in which they use `p:ajax` with `update` attribute instead of `render` and `process` instead of `execute` but the idea is the same (using wrapper and pointing to it)