# Popup not rendering in JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a4j command button in one xhtml page and popup panel in other. I want to open the  the popup on commandbutton click in first page.
the command button

**auth.xhtml**

```
<a4j:commandButton id="Add" value="Add New" type="submit"
   action="#{controller.add}"
   render=":addPopupForm:addPopupOp">
     <a4j:param value="true" assignTo="#{controller.ind}" ></a4j:param>
</a4j:commandButton>
```

**addPopup.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="addPopupForm">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="addPopupOp" ajaxRendered="true">
       <rich:popupPanel id="addPopup" domElementAttachment="parent" show="true"
          rendered="true" height="600" width="1000" >
            Row is added
       </rich:popupPanel>
   </rich:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a richfaces user but in general JSF , you can't re-render elements which are not rendered in the first place.

So in your case you should point to `addPopupForm` , like this :

```
 <a4j:commandButton id="Add" value="Add New" type="submit"
   action="#{controller.add}"
   render=":addPopupForm" >
```

Or wrap the `a4j:outputPanel` with some wrapper that will be always rendered

Also, take a look at this: [Can you update an h:outputLabel from a p:ajax listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370268/617373)

Comment: Can the component in one file access component in other file?

Comment: yes it can access component from other file, as long as one of included in the other using the `ui:include`

Comment: Ok i will try ui:include then as my popup is in other file

Comment: well, since i;m not a richfaces expert, I can't help more, you can  look for some tutorials , or how it can be done on primefaces maybe..

Comment: Hi when I tried showcase popup panel example from this url [linl](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&skin=blueSky) even that isnt working. what can be the issue?

Comment: It works on the url but when i copy the code and run it in eclipse it doesnt on my localhost

Comment: look than for some richfaces basic tutorial, like hello world, again, I'm not a richfaces user, so I can't help you too much.

Answer (score 0):

Just rendering the panel does not mean showing it. You have to attach the popup "show" attribute to a property:

```
show="#{bean.showPopup}"
```

Set the showPopup boolean in the action method (action="#{controller.add}") and then do render="addPopupForm"